# Does anybody know why Debian doesn't give low-latency kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel

Debian has few kernels, the -generic one, -rt kernel, some hardware architecture kernels and hurd. But it doesn't give -lowlatency kernel. Does anybody know the reason why is it so ?

Comment: Debian doesn't have a `-generic` or `-rt` kernel. Do you mean Ubuntu?

Comment: @jordanm there are RT images [in Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-2-rt-amd64-unsigned). `-generic` is indeed a Ubuntu thing...

Answer (score 1):

I would guess there's no technological issue but there's just no maintainer that would have volunteered to maintain the packages to do it.

You can always get sources for the default kernel package and change kernel configuration to enable following options to match Ubuntu `low-latency` package:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT=y
CONFIG_PREEMPTION=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_RCU=y
CONFIG_PREEMPT_NOTIFIERS=y
```

and then just rebuild the kernel packages. Of course, you have to redo that for every security update.

Note that Ubuntu `low-latency` kernel is not the same as `RT` patches that implement true real time support.